# backpropagation implementation - how to apply chain rule on matrix

Tags: python, numpy, backpropagation

### Gradient of `dL/dX` using chain rule

Providing `L` is the loss of the neural network, `X` is an input, and Y is the output of the dot product `Y = X•W = np.dot(X, W)`.

As per the chain rule,  `dL/dX → dY/dX • dL/dY → W.T • dL/dY` because `dY/dX = W` for the product `Y = X•W`.

### Question 1

How can I apply the chain rule formula `dL/dX → W.T • dL/dY` to a matrix? Simply apply it as below does not work because of the shape mismatch where `W.T` is `(4, 3)` and `dL/dY` is `(4,)`.

What thinking, rationale or transformation can I apply to get over this? I believe a different thinking is required for matrix.

```
        # gradient dy (dL/dY) back-propagated from the posterior layer
        dy = self.posterior.backward()    

        # Apply chain-rule dL/dX = dY/dX @ dL/dY where dY/dX = W.T
        dx = np.dot(self.w.T, dy)
```

[image]
Note: typos in the diagram. `(,4)` is `(4,)` etc. In my
brain, 1D array of 4 element was `(,4)` but in NumPy, it is
`(4,)`.

### Question 2

What are the rationale of having to transpose `W.T` and `X.T` to make the chain rule work? I think I can use `W` without transpose if I transpose `dL/dY` but please help understand.

---

#### For `dL/dX`

I saw an answer is swapping the positions, but no idea where it came from and why. Why it is OK to change the order of elements in the chain rule?

```
        # dL/dX = dL/dY • W.T instead of W.T • dL/dY 
        dx = np.dot(dy, self.w.T)   # dy(4,) @ w.T(4, 3) -> (3,)
```

#### For `dL/dW`

In the diagram below from the answer, the shape of `X.T (,3)` and `dL/dY (, 4)` are transformed into `(3, 1)` and `(1, 4)` to match the shapes (actually `(2,1) and (1,3)` but to align with the snapshot above), but not sure where it came from and what is the rationale behind.

Answer

- [deep-learning-from-scratch/common/layers.py](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/blob/master/common/layers.py#L61-L67)

[image]

```
    def backward(self, dout):
        dx = np.dot(dout, self.W.T)
        self.dW = np.dot(self.x.T, dout)
        self.db = np.sum(dout, axis=0)
        
        dx = dx.reshape(*self.original_x_shape)  # 入力データの形状に戻す（テンソル対応）
        return dx
```

## Code

In the middle of coding, not tested and will not work.

```
class Affine(object):
    """Affine (MatMul) Layer"""
    def __init__(self, units, weights, optimizer, posteriors: List[object]):
        """Initialize the affine layer.
        
        [X] shape(size, n)
        Aka Batch. An array of input data x with n features (n: 0, 1, ..., n). n=0 is a bias.
        j-th input X[j] is [x(j)(0), x(j)(1), ... x(j)(n)] where bias 'x(j)(0)' is 1.
        Use capital X for batch and x for its individual input.
        
        NOTE: "input" is not limited to the first input data layer e.g. image pixels, 
              but "input" at any layer.

        [weights] shape(n, units)
        k-th neuron (k:0, 1, .. size-1) has its weight vector W(k):[w(k)(0), w(k)(1), ... w(k)(n)].
        w(k)(0) is its bias weight. Each w(k)(i) amplifies i-th feature in the input x.  
                
        Args:
            units: number of neurons in the layer
            weights: array of weight-vectors of each neuron. shape(n, size)
            optimizer: gradient descent implementation e.g SGD, Adam.
            posteriors: next layers
        """
        # neuron weight vectors
        self.w: numpy.ndarray = weights  # weight vector per neuron
        self.n: int = weights.shape[0]   # number of features expected
        self.dw: numpy.ndarray = None    # gradient of W
        
        self.X: numpy.ndarray = np.empty(0, self.n)     # Batch input
        self.m: int  = -1                # batch size: X.shape[0]

        self.posterior = posteriors[0]
        
        
    def forward(self, X):
        """Forward propagation of the affine layer X@W"""
        # X@W from X(m, n) @ W(n, units) to generate output Y(m, units)
        self.m = self.X.shape[0] if self.X is not None else -1
        Y = np.dot(self.X, self.w)
        self.posterior.forward(Y)


    def backward(self):
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Back propagation dy from the posterior layer. dy shape must match that of Y(m, units)
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        dy = self.posterior.backward()    # gradient back-propagated from the posterior 
        assert(dy.shape[0] == self.m), \
        "gradient dy shape {} must match output Y shape ({}, {})".format(
            dy.shape, self.m, self.n
        )

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Gradient descent on W
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        dw = np.dot(self.X.T, dy)
        self.w = self.optimizer.(self.w, dw)

        dx = np.dot(dy, self.w)
        return dx
```

## Related

A suggestion is given to look at the question below as in [How to apply chain rule on matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979526/how-to-apply-chain-rule-on-matrix).

- [A matrix calculus problem in backpropagation encountered when studying Deep Learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970202/a-matrix-calculus-problem-in-backpropagation-encountered-when-studying-deep-lear)

[image]

## Geometry

In my understanding, `X•W` is extracting the `W` dimension part of `X` by truncating the other dimensions of `X` geometrically. If so,  `dL/dX` and `dL/dW` are  restoring the truncated dimensions? Not sure this is correct but if so, would it be possible to visualize it like `X•W` projection in the diagram?

[image]

Comment: I feel your issue is more mathematical than programmatical in nature and a different stackexchange site would be more appropriate. That said, the way to understand why the results are what they are, i.e., `dx = np.dot(dy, self.w.T)`, is expanding all matrix calculations and following them through. https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~justincj/teaching/eecs442/notes/linear-backprop.html

Comment: @Reti43, thank you, it is so helpful. The cs231n guy moved from Stanford to Michigan...

Comment: @Reti43, would you mind creating an answer? I believe the link you provided will help others when then implement the back-propagation code in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Reti43](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243104/reti43) for pointing to the reference. The detail math is provided by the cs231 Justin Jonson (now in Michigan University) as http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/linear-backprop.pdf which is also available as [Backpropagation for a Linear Layer](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejustincj/teaching/eecs442/notes/linear-backprop.html).

[cs231n lecture 4](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2019/cs231n_2019_lecture04.pdf) explains the idea.

[image]

The math calculation from step (5) to (6) seems to be a leap, because dot product would not be resulted from two 2D matrices, and `numpy.dot` would produce matrix multiplication as `np.matmul`, hence it would not be a dot product.

The answer in [numpy function to use for mathematical dot product to produce scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671687/4281353) addressed a way.

[image]

---

My understanding by reading through the Justin Johnson's paper is below.

### Format of the Weight vector W

Need to note on the weights representation of `W` by Justin Johnson.

In Coursera ML course, Andrew Ng uses a row vector to capture weights of a node. When the number of features in input to a layer is `n`, the row vector size is `n`.

Justin Johnson uses a row vector to represent a layer size, the number of nodes in a layer. Hence if there are `m` nodes in a layer, the row vector size is `m`.

Hence the weight matrix for Andrew Ng is `m x n` meaning m rows of weight vectors, each of which are weights for `n` features for a specific node. The weight matrix for Justin Johnson is `n x m` meaning n rows of weight vectors, each of which are weights for `m` nodes in a layer, per feature.

[image]

I suppose Justin Johnson regards `layer is a function` whereas Andrew Ng regards `node is a function`.

As I studied Andrew Ng's ML course first, I am using `weight vector per node` approach which results in `W as m x n matrix`. My confusion came from applying `W = m x n` to Justin Jhonson's paper.

### Dimension analysis

First frame the dimensions/shapes of the gradients.

[image]

### Derive the gradient

Using the simple one input record `X shape(d,)`, derive the `dL/dX` and extend it to two dimensional input `X shape(n, d)` resulting in `W.T @ dL/dY`.

#### dL/dX

Using row-order matrix for X and W. The result is different from that of cs321 because how to organize weights W is different.

[image]

#### dL/dW.T

Using row-order matrix for X and W. The result is different from that of cs321 because how to organize weights W is different.

[image]
If something incorrect, very much appreciate any feedbacks.