# numpy function to use for mathematical dot product to produce scalar

Tags: numpy, dot-product

## Question

What numpy function to use for mathematical dot product in the case below?

- [Backpropagation for a Linear Layer](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejustincj/teaching/eecs442/notes/linear-backprop.html)

[image]

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: `dot` of a (2,3) with a (3,2) produces a (2,2).

Answer (score 1):

Define sample (2,3) array:

```
In [299]: dldx = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [300]: w
Out[300]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Element wise multiplication:

```
In [301]: dldx*w
Out[301]: 
array([[0. , 0.2, 0.6],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

and summing on the last axis (size 3) produces a 2 element array:

```
In [302]: (dldx*w).sum(axis=1)
Out[302]: array([0.8, 0. ])
```

Your (6) is the first term, dropping the 0.  One might argue that the use of a dot/inner in (5) is a bit sloppy.

`np.einsum` borrows ideas from physics, where dimensions may be higher.  This case can be expressed as

```
In [303]: np.einsum('ij,ik->i',dldx,w)
Out[303]: array([1.8, 0. ])
```

`inner` and `dot` do more calculations that we want.  We just want the diagonal:

```
In [304]: np.dot(dldx,w.T)
Out[304]: 
array([[0.8, 0. ],
       [2.6, 0. ]])
In [305]: np.inner(dldx,w)
Out[305]: 
array([[0.8, 0. ],
       [2.6, 0. ]])
```

In `matmul/@` terms, the size 2 dimension is a 'batch' one, so we have to add dimensions:

```
In [306]: dldx[:,None,:]@w[:,:,None]
Out[306]: 
array([[[0.8]],

       [[0. ]]])
```

This is (2,1,1), so we need to squeeze out the 1s.